# An exersise in Linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new in differential equations. I saw somewhere an exercise an I want to share with you and also to answer me on some questions. So, we consider the linear dif. eq. of first order:
$$y'=\frac{1}{x}y+\frac{1}{x}b(x),\  x>0 $$ where b is a continues function on $(0,+\infty)$.

a) Give conditions such that every solution y of the previus equation satisfies $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} y(x)=0. $$
b) Give conditions in order to to exist a solution y of the previus equation such that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+ } y(x)\in R . $$

I find the solution $$y=y(x)= x\left( y(1)+\int_1^x \frac{1}{s^2}b(s) ds\right),\ x>0 .$$
So for (a) I suppose that $y(1)=0$ , the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{s^2}b(s) ds<\infty$ and $b(x)\to 0$, when x goes to intinity. Then, by L' Hospital rule I got the result. First question, I think that the condition I gave for the integral is not exactly the condition we want (i.e. the best condition). I belive the condition must be in function b(x) such that the general integral exist and equals to $0$.

Also, for (b) I just gave the condition the general integral $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_1^x \frac{1}{s^2} b(s)ds=- \lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_x^1 \frac{1}{s^2} b(s)ds \in R$$, but I am sure that this is a wrong thought. I may lost the point here.
So, could someone help me to understand the fully thought of those exersises. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question I'm not sure but if you suppose that $|b(x)|\leq x^{3/2}, \ \forall x>0$, then the general integral $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_1^x \frac{1}{s^2} b(s)ds=- \lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_x^1 \frac{1}{s^2} b(s)ds$  will be a real number, because the general integral $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} ds$ converges.

Comment: It looks fine to me, thanks. Anyone else may help?